cisco nexus 93180lc-ex urpf for ipv6 not working
when i want to enable urpf for ipv6 in my cisco nexus 93180lc-ex by executing ipv6 verify unicast source reachable-via any rx it will show the following error
IPv6 Unicast Reverse Path Forwarding not supported on this platform


my nxos version is 9.3


We cannot magically make a feature that is unsupported for a platform work on that platform.

Are you using IPv4 rpf? Some N9k models are limited to one stack, not both.

yes i have enabled urpf for ipv4

According to the Cisco Nexus Switch Platform Support Matrix, uRPF for IPv6 is not supported on Nexus 93180lc-ex - it's only listed for Unicast RPF (IPv4 only), not for Unicast RPF (for IPv4 and IPv6)).
